# Problem with accents (encoding) on Mac and Iphone

Tags: iphone, macos, encoding, diacritics, french

I am using a Mac and I am using the App 'Mail' to send and receive my mail. The configuration of my Mac is in Italian as I am Italian.

Problem: I am mostly sending my messages in French with accents and in the messages I sent or receive all my accents are replaced by '?'.

I believe it coming from the encoding of my Mac set up in Italian.

How can I set my App 'Mail' to send and receive messages with accents (encoding UTF-8)

I have this issue on my Mac and on my Iphone !!!

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score -1):

I recommend setting up your Mac so that you use a consistent language for app preserences and the OS preferences. Make sure you haev the latest macos version for your machine.